# Object reference details in Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I need to analyze the objects which are in garbage collection. I can able to generate gc.log file at end of the execution. Is there any way to get the reference of objects in GC from gc.log file?

Comment: Actually intrigued: Why would you need that information?

Comment: well there are [`PhantomReference`s](http://www.baeldung.com/java-phantom-reference) for handling objects in code but that's a very manual process and the closest you could probably get to the desired result is to write your own log file

Comment: I need to analyze whether particular objects are collected by GC or not. I can analyze the heap dump using visualVM at a particular time. Is there any way to get the object references from gc.log file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get the reference of objects in GC from gc.log file?

No there isn't.

As you have already identified, the solution would be to analyze a heap dump.   The trick would be to get the JVM to do a heap dump just before the JVM exits.

Here's an Oracle blog that described how to trigger a heap dump from Java code:

- [Programmatically dumping heap from Java applications](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/programmatically-dumping-heap-from-java-applications)